# getifaddrs ordering -- lo is always first?

Tags: c, glibc

I'm currently using the `getifaddrs` method to enumerate the network interfaces. It always returns the loopback first on my test machines. I couldn't see anything about ordering in the official docs for that method. Can I rely on that ordering?

Comment: Why would you want to rely on the ordering? Are the interfaces unlabeled?

Comment: I want them sorted from fastest to slowest.

Comment: But that's generally very different from any default ordering regardless. You'd have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that requires this behavior.  If you are writing code that will be used on other platforms, you should be prepared for the list to vary.  However, on platforms where loopback appears first it will typically always appear first.

This is largely a result of how network interfaces are initialized.  Since the loopback adapter does not usually require any additional drivers to be loaded, it will tend to be first in the linked list.